# How can I change the divider color of an action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I change that holo blue colored divider to a holo green colored divider? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the ActionBar style generator. [This](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=9c0%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) is an example with a green accent.

Comment: thanks. I've now generated the approriate /res/ files and dropped them into my project. How do I now reference them so that style is used by the action bar?

Comment: Set the theme generated as your application theme.